# How to get back to the previous activity in Gluon after opening a file using ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am developing an application similar to email client. The view 'A' is a list of messages on clicking a message the message details is show along with a list of attachments as view 'B'. On clicking one of the attachments by opening a new Intent with ACTION_VIEW (View 'C').

I am not able to go back to the message details view 'B' on clicking the back button in Android.
(Need multiple clicks to go back)
Also the ListView of attachments is not responding to clicks after coming back.

This is how I am launching the Intent

```
    @Override
public void openFile(String absoluteFilePath) {
    try
{
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
FXActivity.getInstance().startActivityForResult(intent, 36); 
FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((requestCode, resultCode, data)
    -> {         
             if (requestCode == 36) {

                 try {
                 SwtichViewHelper.switchToPrevious();
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                 }

             }
 }); 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}

    }
```

Output on clicking back until View B is seen

```
12-15 12:56:19.910 28138 28138 V FXActivity: onActivityResult with requestCode 36 and resultCode = 0 and intent = null
12-15 12:56:19.910 28138 28138 I System.out: result code ****** 36
12-15 12:56:19.910 28138 28138 I System.out: result code  36  handler******
12-15 12:56:19.912 28138 28138 I System.out: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
12-15 12:56:19.912 28138 28138 V FXActivity: onActivityResult with requestCode 36 and resultCode = 0 and intent = null
12-15 12:56:19.912 28138 28138 I System.out: result code ****** 36
12-15 12:56:19.912 28138 28138 I System.out: result code  36  handler****** 
12-15 12:56:19.913 28138 28138 V FXActivity: onRestart
12-15 12:56:19.915 28138 28138 V FXActivity: onStart
12-15 12:56:19.915 28138 28138 V FXActivity: onResume
12-15 12:56:19.915 28138 28163 I System.out: Application is resumed.**************************
12-15 12:56:19.926 28138 28138 V FXEntity: Surface created.
```

Error after every unsuccessful back :

```
2-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 3963:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
12-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
12-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
12-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
12-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager:       at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
12-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
12-15 13:19:09.268  1539 19855 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 3963:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager:       at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
12-15 13:19:09.290  1539  4670 E ActivityManager:       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
12-15 13:19:09.356  6284  6284 I GoogleInputMethod: onFinishInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
```

Comment: If I get it right, your A and B views are Gluon `View`s? And C is an Android view/app? How do you launch the intent, with Android specific code? Are you using `startActivityForResult`? A little bit of code will help...

Comment: Yes views A and B are Gluon Views and on clicking the attachment item in View B I  call the above native Android specific code to open the file using ACTION_VIEW

Comment: For starters, declare `setOnActivityResultHandler` _before_ `startActivityForResult`. And print out the received `requestCode` before the test.

Comment: Placed the setOnActivityResultHandler before the startActivityForResult. Tha handler code is is executed  but only after multiple clicks (executed multiple times as well) Please see the debug output above

Comment: Have a look at the Camera [service](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/153d43c06ff129f1ff93cc48a030c3a2cf099281/plugins/plugin-pictures/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidPicturesService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) in Charm Down, and the use of `Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop` to stop the JavaFX thread until the new activity finishes.